# Como utilizar ngfor con ngif para crear botones

Tags: ionic, angular

Quiero utilizar el ngfor para obtener 4 datos almacenados y crear los 4 botones con ese dato y dependiendo de la elección que este lo re direccione a la pagina que le corresponde.

```
   <button id="menu-button11" ion-button color="positive" block icon-right style="text-align:left;" >
{{menu.name}}    {{menu.menu1}} {{menu.menu2}}  {{menu.menu3}}  //dependiendo de este valor llamar a la pagina correspondiente
       <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Hay alguna forma de hacer eso?

Answer (score 1):

crea los botones de manera dinamica con el ngFor, y dentro del elemento button agrega el ngIf para manejar tu condición, dentro de los datos del botón tambien debes añadir la pagina a donde va a redireccionar, aquí un ejemplo:

.HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let boton of botones">
   <button *ngIf="boton.valor == 1" ion-button (click)="goTo(boton.pagina)">{{boton.etiqueta}}</button>
</div>
```

.TS:

```
export class MyPage {
 botones: any = [
    {etiqueta: "Boton Uno", pagina: "HomePage", valor: 1}, 
    {etiqueta: "Boton Dos", pagina: "UsersPage", valor: 2}
 ]

 goTo(pagina){
    this.navCtrl.push(pagina);
 }
}
```

Esta solución implica utilizar [lazy loading](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/) para navegar entre las paginas